# Denegacion de la carpeta "resources" en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problema con Laravel:
al ejecutar el comando "php artisan serve" me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ocasiones anteriores este error lo he solucionado creando de nuevo el script "server.php" dentro del directorio: "C:\xampp\htdocs"nombre del proyecto"\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\resources". Pero ahora este directorio me niega el acceso únicamente al crear de nuevo dicho script. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente con las opciones avanzadas de seguridad de las propiedades de la carpeta pero no dio resultado.

Realmente este proyecto tiene bastante trabajo y no puedo perderlo. Me ayudaria mucho saber si alguien sabe algo de este extraño error.

Comment: Es el directorio vendor no? Has probado borrando la carpeta y reinstalandolo con `composer i`?